# Creating a test suite from multiple test cases

Tags: python, python-unittest

I've been get myself acquainted with the unittest library in Python, and I've written up several `unitest.TestCase`s which look similar to this:

```
class TestOne(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def first_test(self):
        self.assertEqual('a', 'b')

    def second_test(self):
        self.assertEqual('a', 'b')

    def third_test(self):
        self.assertEqual('a', 'b')

    def tearDown(self):
        pass


class TestTwo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def first_test(self):
        self.assertEqual('a', 'b')

    def second_test(self):
        self.assertEqual('a', 'b')

    def third_test(self):
        self.assertEqual('a', 'b')

    def tearDown(self):
        pass


class TestThree(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def first_test(self):
        self.assertEqual('a', 'b')

    def second_test(self):
        self.assertEqual('a', 'b')

    def third_test(self):
        self.assertEqual('a', 'b')

    def tearDown(self):
        pass
```

Now that isn't what my code looks like exactly, but that is the basic structure that is followed.

I know that if I want to execute a single `TestCase`, I can do this:

```
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestOne)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

However, I've been struggling with getting multiple `TestCase`s to run at the same time.

I've tried doing this:

```
suite = unittest.TestSuite()
suite.addTest(TestOne())
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

But that throws the error:

```
ValueError: no such test method in <class 'unit_tests.TestOne'>: runTest
```

I know I would use a `runTest` method if I had only a single test per case, but I have several, all of which need to be their own individual tests inside of a `TestCase`.

I've tried poring through the `unittest` documentation, but I have been unable to figure out what to do to run tests from multiple test cases from within a single test suite.

I've looked at `nosetests`, and it does what I want to do without me having to make any modifications to my code, but I would like to know if there is a way to run tests from multiple cases in a suite without depending on an external library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try to create a TestSuite from a list of suites created with TestLoader? This is an example adapted from Python documentation:

```
suite1 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestOne)
suite2 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestTwo)
alltests = unittest.TestSuite([suite1, suite2])
```