# How to run unittest tests from multiple directories

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have 2 directories containing tests:

```
project/
|
|-- test/
|    |
|    |-- __init__.py
|    |-- test_1.py
|
|-- my_submodule/
     |
     |-- test/
          |
          |-- __init__.py
          |-- test_2.py
```

How can I run all tests?

`python -m unittest discover .`
only runs `test_1.py`

and obviously
`python -m unittest discover my_submodule`
only runs `test_2.py`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unittest` currently sees `project/my_submodule` as an arbitrary directory to ignore, not a package to import. Just add `project/my_submodule/__init__.py` to change that.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use a test suite file

A possible solution is to write a test suite file as following:

```
import unittest

from test import test_1
from my_submodule.test import test_2

loader = unittest.TestLoader()
suite = unittest.TestSuite()

suite.addTest(loader.loadTestsFromModule(test_1))
suite.addTest(loader.loadTestsFromModule(test_2))

runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=3)

result = runner.run(suite)
```

Save the previous file in your folder `project` and call it `runner_test.py`. The code uses 3 class of the module `unittest`:

- `TestLoader` ---> see the instruction:

```
loader = unittest.TestLoader()
```

- `TestSuite` ---> see instructions:

```
suite = unittest.TestSuite()
suite.addTest(...)
```

- `TextTestRunner` ---> see instructions:

```
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=3)
result = runner.run(suite)
```

Info about these classes can be found [into the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html).

I have written two example test files as following:

*project/test/test_1.py*

```
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_1(self):
        print("test1")
        self.assertEqual("test1", "test1")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

*project/my_submodule/test/test_2.py*

```
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_1(self):
        print("test1")
        self.assertEqual("test1", "test1")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

If you execute the following command:

```
> cd /path/to/folder/project

> python runner_test.py
```

The output of previous command (`python runner_test.py`) is:

```
test_1 (test.test_1.MyTestCase) ... test1
ok
test_2 (my_submodule.test.test_2.MyTestCase) ... test2
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

---

##### Note

There are many other ways to write a test suite: for example see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792303/creating-a-test-suite-from-multiple-test-cases) and links connected to it.