# Python how to run unit tests from different packages?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Here is my folder structure:

```
src/
src/package1
src/package1/package1
src/package1/package1/__init__.py
src/package1/package1/class_package1.py
src/package1/package1/test_package1.py
src/package2
src/package2/package2
src/package1/package2/__init__.py
src/package2/package2/class_package1.py
src/package2/package2/test_package1.py
```

This is a ROS2 packages structure, I can't modify it.

- Running `python -m unittest` from `src/package1/package1` runs all
  `package1` tests
- Running `python -m unittest` from
  `src/package2/package2` runs all `package2` tests
- Running `python -m unittest discover package1/package1` from `src` runs all `package1`
  tests
- Running `python -m unittest discover package2/package2` from
  `src` runs all `package2` tests

However, is there a way to run all `package1` AND `package2` tests from `src` folder?

I suppose moving all tests to a new `test` package could make this work easily but I'd like to avoid that. I like tests to remain close to code itself.

Comment: Does `python -m unittest discover` (without package specification) work?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych: No, it reports no test found

Comment: @jpo38 [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75322357/how-to-run-unittest-tests-from-multiple-directories/75324290#75324290) could help you?

Comment: @User051209: Not exactly what I'm looking for because I want to do this from a command line but thanks.

Comment: @jpo38 You can define a file `runner_test.py` (as explained in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75322357/how-to-run-unittest-tests-from-multiple-directories/75324290#75324290)) in the folder `src` and execute `python runner_test.py` by command line. I don't know if it is possible avoid writing code to solve your problem.